# How to change the src of a iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Im trying to create a function that changes the src of iframe.
I created a array of the url of the four locations.
but i dont know if i must use `const matches = document.querySelectorAll("iframe[data-src]");` or a `document.getElementById('myIframe').src`.
im pretty new in coding in general.
Every advice or suggestion will be very welcome.

HTML

`<iframe id= "myiframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d209569.44700750793!2d-56.380275318336025!3d-34.84309361411796!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x959f802b6753b221%3A0x3257eb39860f05a6!2sPalacio%20Salvo!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614269355326!5m2!1sen!2suy" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" class ="maps-gallery active"></iframe>`

Javascript

```
function maps(){
var mapsArray = [
"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d209569.44700750793!2d-56.380275318336025!3d-34.84309361411796!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x959f802b6753b221%3A0x3257eb39860f05a6!2sPalacio%20Salvo!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614269355326!5m2!1sen!2suy",
"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d92110.09563909167!2d17.958933187703266!3d59.32686333113927!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x465f763119640bcb%3A0xa80d27d3679d7766!2sStockholm%2C%20Sweden!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614704350417!5m2!1sen!2suy",
"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d88989.45462143555!2d15.9390973!3d45.8128514!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4765d701f8ef1d1d%3A0x312b512f1e7f6df9!2sCathedral%20of%20Zagreb!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614704668458!5m2!1sen!2suy",
"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6709.917127499258!2d-78.51409209928569!3d0.3576385746900253!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8e2a5da2881494ab%3A0xae89047fc027c897!2sapuela%20imbabura%20intac!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614704741586!5m2!1sen!2suy"

];
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = maps[Math.floor(Math.random() * maps.length)];

}
```

Comment: Since you have an `id`, just use that. Also, you have a difference between the `id` names. In you JS, you type `myIframe` while your HTML uses `myiframe`. Capitalization matters.

Comment: i fixed the capitalization. thanks.
but i dont know how to use it proporly the function to change the src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your variable names are consistent, and that you actually call the function somewhere.

(You had both `myiframe` and `myIframe` as the frame ID, and inside `maps()` you defined `mapsArray` but then try to access it as `maps` instead.)

```js
function maps() {
  var mapsArray = [
    "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d209569.44700750793!2d-56.380275318336025!3d-34.84309361411796!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x959f802b6753b221%3A0x3257eb39860f05a6!2sPalacio%20Salvo!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614269355326!5m2!1sen!2suy",
    "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d92110.09563909167!2d17.958933187703266!3d59.32686333113927!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x465f763119640bcb%3A0xa80d27d3679d7766!2sStockholm%2C%20Sweden!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614704350417!5m2!1sen!2suy",
    "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d88989.45462143555!2d15.9390973!3d45.8128514!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4765d701f8ef1d1d%3A0x312b512f1e7f6df9!2sCathedral%20of%20Zagreb!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614704668458!5m2!1sen!2suy",
    "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6709.917127499258!2d-78.51409209928569!3d0.3576385746900253!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8e2a5da2881494ab%3A0xae89047fc027c897!2sapuela%20imbabura%20intac!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suy!4v1614704741586!5m2!1sen!2suy"
  ];
  document.getElementById('myIframe').src = mapsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * mapsArray.length)];
}

maps();
```

```html
<iframe id='myIframe'></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you for your response...but i still have trouble to update my url in my iframe

Comment: Well, @Alesito, it's working in the snippet above. If you're still having trouble you'll need to explain what sort of trouble you're having, instead of expecting us to guess.

Comment: becouse i want to use next and previous buttons for changing for each location.

Comment: OK, that'd be a matter of choosing a specific element from the array for your 'next' and 'previous' buttons instead of choosing a random one; if you have trouble with that it may be worth opening it as a separate question, since this one made no mention of it.